# SSLHandShake Exception when trying to image from URL

Tags: android, image, url, imageview, sslhandshakeexception

I am running a Android Program to Load image through URL, but it is giving me SSLHandShakeException. Can anyone suggest what should i add in code to remove it?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
ImageView iv;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageload);
    LoadImageFromURL loadImage = new LoadImageFromURL();
    loadImage.execute();
}   

 public class LoadImageFromURL extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap>{

     @Override
     protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub

     try {
     URL url = new URL("https://www.babyboomapps.com/members/upload-album-files/1436952341Hydrangeas.jpg");
    /* InputStream is = url.openConnection().getInputStream();
     Bitmap bitMap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
     compress(bitMap);*/

     downloadImage(""+url);
     return null;

     } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     e.printStackTrace();
     } catch (IOException e) {
     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     e.printStackTrace();
     }
     return null;

     }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        iv.setImageBitmap(result);
    }
}


 public void compress(Bitmap bitMap){

     Bitmap original = bitMap;
     ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
     original.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
     Bitmap decoded = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray()));

     Log.e("Original   dimensions", original.getWidth()+" "+original.getHeight());
     Log.e("Compressed dimensions", decoded.getWidth()+" "+decoded.getHeight());
 }


/* public void hostnameverifier() throws UnknownHostException, IOException{

     SocketFactory sf = javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
     SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket) sf.createSocket("babyboom.com", 8443);
     HostnameVerifier hv = HttpsURLConnection.getDefaultHostnameVerifier();
     SSLSession s = socket.getSession();

     // Verify that the certicate hostname is for mail.google.com
     // This is due to lack of SNI support in the current SSLSocket.
     if (!hv.verify("babyboom.com", s)) {
         throw new SSLHandshakeException("Expected babyboom.com"  + s.getPeerPrincipal());
     }

     // At this point SSLSocket performed certificate verificaiton and
     // we have performed hostname verification, so it is safe to proceed.

     // ... use socket ...
     socket.close();
 }*/

   // Creates Bitmap from InputStream and returns it
    private Bitmap downloadImage(String url) {
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        InputStream stream = null;
        BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bmOptions.inSampleSize = 4;

        try {
            stream = getHttpConnection(url);
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream, null, bmOptions);
            stream.close();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bitmap;
    }


    private InputStream getHttpConnection(String urlString)
            throws IOException {
        InputStream stream = null;
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();

        try {
            HttpsURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) connection;
            httpConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpConnection.connect();

            Log.d(getClass().getName(), "response code:--- "+httpConnection.getResponseCode());
            if (httpConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK ||
                    httpConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_NOT_MODIFIED) {

                stream = httpConnection.getInputStream();
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return stream;
    }
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
}
```

Comment: Try "http://" not "https". You don't send sertificate to server.

Comment: I have tried but it is also not working ..

Comment: Did you check that site, this website's certificate is out of date, and http:// not working. You have to download this using certificate. Here is how to download over ssl: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17974733/how-to-download-file-over-ssl-https-on-android